# How to create autocomplete with data from code behind?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xmldocument

In my Main.aspx.cs i have a `XmlDocument`. With:

```
var personName = dataXml.SelectNodes("/GetDocumentsResult/Person/Name");
string[] perNames = new string[personName .Count];

for (int i = 0; i < personName .Count; i++)
{            
    perNames[i] = personName [i].InnerText;
}
```

i get the names of all persons.
In Main.aspx i have a search input:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="LEFT:15px;TOP:10px;">
  <input name="suche" id="searchinput1"  value="" type="search">
</div>
```

There are many links with autocomplete such as [this link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) , but i dont know how to use `perNames` in aspx.

Comment: You could write the values to the page as javascript, or move that code to a web service and use that service as the data source.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to write the values to the page as javascript?

Comment: Look into JSON serializing and write the resulting string to a `Literal` control. Though using a web service would probably be better.

Comment: i found out using `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` i can serialize, but how to use the JSON object inside the `<script>` tag inside `<head>` tag?

Comment: You should be able to create a `Literal` and do something like `MyLiteral.Text = "var autoCompleteData = " + SerializedXml;` then in your javascript, access the `autoCompleteData` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JQuery for the front end part, as is pretty straight forward, then you need to use AJAX to get a list of data, and then you got your business and backend part as is usual business. Take a look here.

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-jQuery-AutoComplete-Plugin-in-ASP.Net.aspx